# Play Framework 1.2.4: Routing jsp files

Tags: jsp, redirect, playframework, migration, routes

I'm in the process of migrating a legacy application onto the Play Framework and I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect our old legacy *.jsp routes to the framework. Ex:

```
# Old home
/home.jsp              MainController.home
# New home
/home                  MainController.home

# Old random page
/foo/bar.jsp           FooController.bar
# new random page
/random/bar            FooController.bar
```

This works fine when I'm testing on localhost but I'll get 404 errors when I deploy to my Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the web.xml that is generated by Play.

You should see a line, as below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>play</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Try adding the following line inside the `servlet-mapping` tag.

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Since play was the only servlet I needed, I went ahead and used /* as my url-pattern. Thanks, Codemwnci.